# In excel VBA, I am looking for VBA code that adds a new line item with the latest month end each time the spreadsheet opens

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I currently have a spreadsheet that has individual line items for each month end. Starting in A1, 1/31/2021 and A5, 5/31/2021 for example. My goal is, each month when I open the spreadsheet, a new line item is created for that month; so if it's 5/21/2021 and I open the spreadsheet, it will create a line item with 5/31/2021. Is it possible to include logic that checks the current month I'm in and will open add a line item if it's relevant for the appropriate month?

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98T-KbkCmw16RmYGU?e=f1xoXS) refer:
*(note - for security reasons, linked sheet above has not VB code - this needs to be built in as described below).*

**High level**

This soln. requires following: 2 named ranges, macro-enabled workbook.  Office 365 not necessary.

**Setup**

1. Enter any date you wish in column A (max capacity = 100)

**Ranges**

2. Create named formula: Formulas | Name Manager | New… set name = 'dates'; enter formula: `=$A$1:OFFSET($A$1,COUNTA(1,1000)-1,0,1,1)`

*(This is a dynamic (automatically grows to accommodate your list of dates in column A)*

3. As for 2) but with following: name : 'Required' (w/ apostrophes), formula = `=IFERROR(IF(YEAR(INDEX(dates,MATCH(MONTH(TODAY()),MONTH(dates),0)))=YEAR(TODAY()),0,1),1)`

*(this creates a formula that checks whether any of the dates in col    A already have the current month.  i.e. 'Required' = 0 if month already exists (for current year); else 1 returned)*

**VB**

Let the fun begin!

1. Alt + F11 (open VB for Excel running on Windows)
2. Locate your file in the Project Explorer (typically default window pane on left hand side; if no such pane, then  select from the upper ribbon/menu bar: View  | Project Explorer:

[image: Selecting VB Project Explorer if not already displayed per default scheme]

3. Double click the component entitled 'ThisWorkbook' to reveal a new window pane on the right-hand side of the VB window.

[image: ThisWindow component within Project Explorer]

The remaining operations appertain to the VB window pane on the Right Hand Side (RHS)...

There are two menu bars with drop-down functionality at the top of the VB-code pane:

[image: Two drop-down menu bars, top of VB editor / window pane on RHS]

4. Left drop-down / Right drop-down - select respective drop-downs as 'Workbook' and 'Open' respectively, then enter the code per below screenshot (code replicated here for convenience):

[image: Selecting 'Workbook' and 'Open' from the two drop-down menu bars on the RHS/at top of the code editor]

*Code*

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    REQ = Application.Evaluate("Required")
    Range("f5").Value = REQ
    If REQ = 1 Then
        new_date = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
        Sheets("68516961").Range("dates").Offset(1).Value = new_date
    End If
    
End Sub
```

*Voila! You're all set to go! I tested a couple of times and all appears to be working fine.  fyi - don't forget to save as macro-enabled workbook (I prefer .xlsb files as the typically have half the file size compared to .xlsm - the one exception I'm aware of is if there is an SQL connection - in which case it's about the same size as the .xlsm counterpart)...*

**Functionality:**

Every time you open the workbook, the VB code is run - it checks to see if there are any dates that comprise the same month and year as the day your opening the file; if not, the date of 'that day' is automatically populated at the bottom of any existing list of dates in A:A.  This gives you the freedom of being able to include other / manually entered dates or otherwise between successive VB created date appended values.

**Appendices**

Creating named ranges:

[image: Screenshots for creating named ranges in this example]